# How to convert a numpy string array to numpy float array?

Tags: python, numpy

The values look like '"46.1"' in the whole array.The array is generated after reading a csv file. I want the float value out of them. I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: What have you tried? what's the input? What do you expect?

Answer (score 4):

use [`np.astype()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['1.1', '2.2', '3.3'])
print a
# ['"1.1"' '"2.2"' '"3.3"']

b = np.array([x.strip('"') for x in a])
print b
# ['1.1' '2.2' '3.3']

c = a.astype(np.float)
print c
# [ 1.1  2.2  3.3]
```

Comment: I made a small edit to my question. The representation is in form ' "46.1" ' . My bad.